# Android App User Authentication with Wordpress DB

Tags: php, android, sql, wordpress

I need help with my user authentication over my wordpress site using android. I'm sending a request with the login informations (email and password) to a PHP file on my website. In the file I have a SQL statement which should give me the `display_name` from the `wp-users` table. So good so far. I can check the email adress and it works fine but when I want to devide the password (entered in the app) with my password in the wp-users table I get a big problem because the password in the DB is hashed. I've typed my passwort in a hash generator to see if its the same but I wasn't. Can you help me?

SQL:

```html
SELECT display_name FROM wp_users WHERE user_email = "max-mustermann@web.de" AND user_pass = "Test1234!"
```

The email and password is just an example and will be replaced with the variables later.

Comment: What hash algorithm was used to hash the pw stored in your db?

Comment: I don't know but its the standard wordpress algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer to the question. This answer shoes you how you can check a password from a variable with the deposited password in the wp-users table (For a login in my example to check if user typed in the right password).

```html
<?php 
 include_once('wp-includes/class-phpass.php');
 include('wp-content/themes/storefront/db_connection.php'); //In my case I have a database connection php with my db login options
 $loginEmail = "your-email@here.com"; //You can replace it with a $_GET[] or $_POST[] variable
 $loginPassword = "yourpassword" //*
 $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);
 
 //Checking if the $loginPassword equals the password in the wp_users database in Wordpress
 $password_result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT user_pass FROM wp_users WHERE user_email = '$loginEmail'");
 if ($password_result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $password_result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $hashPassword = $row["user_pass"];
  }
 } else {
  //echo some error if no result
 }
 if($hasher->CheckPassword($loginPassword, $hashPassword)) {
  //Send you $loginPassword to Wordpress hasher to check if they are the same
 } else {
  //do something if passwords don't match
 }
?>
```

Comment: Please give me a vote up and mark it as answer if it helps someone :)